# VMPlayer processor allocation

Tags: virtual-machine

I am using very often VMPlayer. (If you don't know what VMPlayer is, quit...)

I am quite interested how processors are used by VMs. As we, users of VMPlayer, already know, giving RAM to VM, means the host cannot use it until Virtual Machine is closed.

But how does it works with processors? I made a graphic, with four choices... !
Please tell me which of four variants is correct... look on legend on right.

[image]

Comment: Should be migrated to SU.

Comment: Thats a rude tone for asking a question!

Answer (score 0):

1. How -on earth- did you manage to have 5 processors on a machine ???? (I presume its only an example, but could not resist)
2. VMplayer, although it uses some kernel modules, it still runs as a User process (at least the guest machine as `vmware-vmx` in linux, check it with `top`), and therefore it is as swappable as any other process. So the host can still use the assigned memory, swapping VM off, although performance will degrade unbearably.
3. As VMplayer is mainly a user-level process, it will run on any processor assigned that same moment. It does not have to exclusively occupy or reside (somehow) to a processor. So any distinct moment, it may reside to any processor - and later change, as the host OS commands.

From VMware site I copied :

> *When a virtual machine is scheduled, its virtual processors are scheduled to run on physical processors.*

Hence, the host OS will schedule the virtual processor, so the host OS defines where the vmplayer guest OS will run each time quantum (or scheduled period if you prefer).
Think, also, that each vCPU may be assigned to anything: a physical CPU, a core or even a thread. A thread cannot be dedicated to any process, neither can a process be always assigned to same thread. That's meaningless.